# Find all Paths in Graph given the Vertices and some Restrictions

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

I try to come up with an algorithm for the following problem, but until now I was not able to solve it. I guess this problem falls into the category of graph problems. Maybe someone can give me a hint to the right keywords/algorithms. :)

So my problem: I have a set of vertices and a number of restrictions. I try to find all the edges between the vertices in regard of the restrictions.

- I have a nxn matrix of vertices
- I have a start (S) and an end (E) (sound's like a network/flow)
- The vertices in the column and row of S and E can be ignored
- S is located at (1,1) in the matrix and E is located at (n,n)
- The graph is directed from S to E, i.e. I have to find a way from the top left to the bottom right. I can not go back.
- For each step through the matrix I have to increase the row and the column
- I have to cross at least one vertex between S and E

Let's take a look at this example:

```
S - - -
- 1 2 -
- 3 4 -
- - - E
```

I can identify the paths

- S > 1 > 4 > E
- S > 3 > E
- S > 2 > E
- S > 4 > E (which will be in our use case the same as S14E, but this doesn't matter rn. If we can filter it out through the algorithm it would be nice, but not a must.)

A more complex example

```
S - - - -
- 1 2 3 -
- 4 5 6 -
- - - - E
```

With the following paths:

- S > 1 > 5 > E
- S > 1 > 6 > E
- S > 1 > E
- S > 2 > 6 > E
- S > 2 > E (which is the same as S26E)*
- S > 3 > E
- S > 4 > E
- S > 5 > E (which is the same as S15E)*
- S > 6 > E

*in our use case

One can also think of the problem of dividing a rectangle with height B and width T into equally sized rectangles. The number of separations of B and T should be modifiable in our use case. See the picture for an example[image]

Comment: Hints: dynamic programming and step (x, y) has to satisfy gcd(x, y)=1.

Answer (score 1):

In comment I hinted on dynamic programming, which is way to solve this problem if only number of solutions are needed. I misread question.

To print all solutions you have to calculate all solutions and that is done by recursion. Step of recursion has property gcd(x, y)=1, since if it is not a case than step would 'jump' over some node(s).

Here is simple python solution that prints results in format you specified.

```
from fractions import gcd

def valid_steps(max_x, max_y):
    for x in xrange(1, max_x+1):
        for y in xrange(1, max_y+1):
            if gcd(x, y) == 1:
                yield x, y

def _solve(n, m, path, xy_2_name):
    x, y = path[-1]
    if x == n and y == m:
        print [xy_2_name[xy] for xy in path]
        return
    for sx, sy in valid_steps(n - x, m - y):
        _solve(n, m, path + [(x+sx, y+sy)], xy_2_name)

def solve(n, m):
    xy_2_name = dict()
    xy_2_name[(1, 1)] = 'S'
    xy_2_name[(n, m)] = 'E'
    c = 1
    for y in xrange(2, m):
        for x in xrange(2, n):
            xy_2_name[(x, y)] = c
            c += 1
    _solve(n, m, [(1, 1)], xy_2_name)

solve(5, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint and solution. I also came up with a recursive solution on my own a few hours after my post and it looks quite similar to yours (as far as I read python correctly ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is helpful, but maybe you could have a look at Theta* (just google 'Theta star'). I'm not sure if that fits your needs, but I feel like you would just need a non-greedy implementation of that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can be solved using a simple shortest path algorithm.

Graph `G = (V,E)`. The edge set `E={(i,j), where row(j) > row(i) and col(j) > col(i) }` In addition, ensure that `(Start,End)` is not part of `E`. Then, it is easy to see that this graph has no directed cycles. Any path from `Start` to `End` is a path that satisfies your constraints. In particular, a shortest path (Easily obtained on applying Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, for instance) satisfies your constraints.

To find all paths between `Start` and `End`, you would need some sort of enumerative algorithm. In general, the number of paths between two nodes in a graph is exponential in size of the graph input size.